# How to exclude replies and retweets from Twitter with Python GetOldTweets3

Tags: python, twitter

I am using python package GetOldTweets3 to extract all tweets from a specific user between a specific timeframe. However, I only want the 'original' tweets, and no public replies or retweets the user makes.

Is there any possibility to do this with GetOldTweets3 or any way to expand the package?

```
    import GetOldTweets3 as got
    tweetCriteria = 
        got.manager.TweetCriteria().setUsername(username).setSince(startdate).setUntil(enddate)
    tweets = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)
```

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

I've been using GetOldTweets3 recently and I don't think that you'll get user retweets from the result. For the replies, you can just get the reply for each record by adding tweet.to to your result and choose the record that has null for that.